# Can I use an observer to insert my module block into product.info?

Tags: event-observer, blocks, module, ce-1.9.1.0, layout-update

I want my custom block to be dependent on whether my module is enabled or not and I want do not want it to be dependent on a theme so using the following, for example, is out of the question: /catalog/product/view.phtml - using getChild().

I am attempting to add a block to product.info. I can update the product page without modifying any default template files if I use  but, of course, if I use....

```
 <reference name="product.info">
```

I cannot show it unless I add a getChild() method to /catalog/product/view.phtml.

Module config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Importer_Nutrition>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </Importer_Nutrition>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <nutrition>
                <class>Importer_Nutrition_Model</class> 
            </nutrition> 
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <nutrition>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Importer_Nutrition</module>
                    <frontName>nutrition</frontName>
                </args>
            </nutrition>
        </routers>  
        <!-- Establish Layout Rules -->
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <nutrition>
                    <file>Importer/Nutrition/product_view.xml</file>
                </nutrition>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <crontab> 
        <jobs>
            <Importer_Fetch_Nutrition_Info> 
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 2 1,5 * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule> 
                <!-- Stocks are being added to database every 30 minutes at H:01 and H:31
                it can take up to 5 minutes to finish, so we are waiting ten minutes after each import -->
                <run>
                    <model>nutrition/Fetchnutritioninfo::run</model>
                </run>
            </Importer_Fetch_Nutrition_Info>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>

</config>
```

[theme]/layout/Importer/Nutrition/product_view.xml

```
 <layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view translate="label"> 
    <reference name="product.info"> 
        <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.nutritionLabel" after="product.description" template="Importer/Nutrition/catalog/product/view/nutritionLabel.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Can I use an observer to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iUseMagentoNow, You cannot add block using Observer `without` using  `getChildHtml('product.nutritionLabel')` at view.phtml.

Because  of at view.phtml file.... view.phtml file's all child block is  not render using `getChildHtml();`

According magento a block all child block are `render using getChildHtml()` that if  we do not send any `param to getChildHtml()` function the  `magento is render all block automatically`.

If send `parameter` then it render `only that particular block`.

**Example:**
Magento default render the media block using below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
```

see at catalog xml is define media block name

Comment: So, from a module point of view how do I add this to the template without overriding any extensions that may have already modified view.phtml?

Comment: from my point of view ,it is not possible at view.phtml

Comment: put this code   <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.nutritionLabel" after="product.description" template="Importer/Nutrition/catalog/product/view/nutritionLabel.phtml" /> at catalog.xml at catalog_product_view handler and check

Comment: Sorry, it came out to a typo after I pasted the suggestion above - hence the comment delete.

For educational purposes, since this must be embedded in view.phtml - where should I apply the logic that dictates whether or not the block is added based on the module being enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 1):

There might be an easier way depending on what you want. Try modifying your layout update file like this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.nutritionLabel" after="product.description" template="importer/nutrition/catalog/product/view/nutritionLabel.phtml">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Nutrition Label</value></action>
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Would something like this work for you?